# Symmetry in product of angular momentum operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

To evaluate $\hat{J}_x\hat{J}_y\psi$, we simply expand each operator: \begin{align*}\hat{J}_x\hat{J}_y\psi &= \left(y\frac{\partial}{\partial z} - z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\left(z\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x} - x\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z}\right)\\ &= y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(z\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right) - y\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(x\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z}\right) - z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(z\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}\right) + z\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(x\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z}\right)\end{align*}

And we can evaluate $\hat{J}_y\hat{J}_x\psi$ similarly:
\begin{align*}\hat{J}_y\hat{J}_x\psi &= \left(z\frac{\partial}{\partial x} - x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\right)\left(y\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z} - z\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}\right)\\ &= z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(y\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z}\right) - z\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(z\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}\right) - x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(y\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial z}\right) + x\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\left(z\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}\right)\end{align*}

It turns out that we could also have obtained $\hat{J}_y\hat{J}_x\psi$ by making the substitution $x \to y$, $y \to x$ in the first equation. Why should this be true *physically*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that wasn't true this would imply that there was a preferred direction of space - that there was something special about the labels x, y, z rather than indexing an arbitrary basis of a 3 dimensional vector space.

**Clarification**

The complete properties of how rotations in three dimensions function (which is what these operators are essentially about) is encoded in the commutation relations which follow from this calculation:

$$[J_x,J_y] = J_xJ_y - J_yJ_x = J_z$$

This relation *is* affected by switching just x and y axes without changing our definition of z. Then we have

$$[J_y,J_x] = J_yJ_x - J_xJ_y = -J_z$$

Comment: Thank you for your response! Even so, the designation of the coordinate axes--and indeed of the definition of the angular momentum operators--is arbitrarily chosen to satisfy a right-hand rule, and the inversion associated with re-labeling the $x$- and $y$- axes leads to a shift to a left-handed coordinate system. Shouldn't that affect anything?

Comment: @a-cyclohexane-molecule I've written a bit more which hopefully thinking about will help. If not we'll have to start again and construct a more rigorous answer!